# How would you merge two columns of a csv file together?

Tags: r

Only 1 csv file and I am trying to merge columns (2,3 columns) that are similar into 1 column.
How would you do this?

I have tried the code below and it does not work as after getting the head of the merged data I still get the two separate columns.

```r
merged_data <- cbind(rw.data, new_column=paste(rw.data$fiveac, rw.data$fiveem))
write.csv(merged_data,"merged.rw.data.csv",row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: `merged_data <- transform(rw.data, new_column=paste(fiveac, fiveem))`

Comment: or `mutate(...)`.

Comment: If that doesn't work correctly for you, please [edit] your question and make this question reproducible by adding sample data (preferably using `dput(head(rw.data))`) and expected output given that sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of approaches. Assume your data looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)

rw.data <- tribble(
  ~fiveac, ~fiveem,
  "A", 1,
  "B", 2,
  "C", 3
)
```

```
  fiveac fiveem
1 A           1
2 B           2
3 C           3
```

**Using {dplyr}**

```
rw.data %>%
  mutate(
    new_column = paste(fiveac, fiveem)
  )
```

```
  fiveac fiveem new_column
1 A           1 A 1       
2 B           2 B 2       
3 C           3 C 3
```

This is the option mentioned by @r2evans. If you don't want space between the values then use `paste0()`. If you only want the `new_column` column in the result then replace `mutate()` with `transmute()`.

**Using {tidyr}**

```
rw.data %>%
  unite(
    "new_column",
    fiveac:fiveem,
    remove = FALSE
  )
```

```
  new_column fiveac fiveem
  <chr>      <chr>   <dbl>
1 A_1        A           1
2 B_2        B           2
3 C_3        C           3
```

If you only want the `new_column` column in the result then set `remove = TRUE`.